# creating update sytem for an android app

Tags: android, auto-update

I am creating an **android monthly e-magazine app** for a business project but I don't know how to create the capacity for the app to have an update system so that every month when the user opens his app new information is be updated automatically from the server.

Comment: you can create a service using alarm manager to run monthly to download update from server and updates ui or stuffs.

Comment: I have never worked on a project applying concepts of server.So which server system should i opt for? what type of server should i rent? Can you give me some link to some website where I can get knowledge about applying server level update?

Answer (score -1):

You my use Google Firebase.
Very Easy to Integrate.

Comment: Switching to a whole new BaaS just to have some auto-update feature! You serious?

Comment: Hi @AnixpasBesoin , this solves not only updating problem but gives a lot of other features like cloud messaging,notifications, remote config etc..takes like 30 minutes for average programmer to integrate..

Comment: That's what a modern BaaS usually offers. I'm aware of how great is Firebase, but what if I'm already having a backend up and running? Would you suggest me to migrate to Firebase?

Comment: Dont mean to disagree with you on that note but the question looks like something from static to DYNAMIC is happening so as to avoid giving app update every month..it was just a suggestion.. if you doubt on efficiency your downvote would have been appreciated by me as well..

Comment: Trust me, there are many ways to fulfill this, it's just that Firebase (or any other BaaS) is an overkill for such thing.

Comment: Hi guys, I am very thankful for your advice.The truth is I am just a student now and I have no knowledge about the update system that apps have. Since I am creating e-magazine app that update its data every month,it is like starting from very scratch. So please give me more advice. Which area should I dig in? What should I opt for?